# Robust RJ45 for frequent connections/disconnections

Tags: cable, rj45

I am looking for robust RJ45 cables/connectors in an environment where people come and go and plug in and out. After a month of usage, the connectors are worn out and fall out and you need to replace the cable. I want to not do it so often - what are my options other than wireless?

**Update:** after some searching, I think I have found what I was looking for. The magic keywords seem to be "cat6 patch leads with strain relief". The most robust I've seen have a long "[sleeve](http://www.dttuk.co.uk/product.htm?product=Krone-Patch-Lead-Cat6-UTP-LSZH-RED)", but [these guys](http://www.comms-express.com/products/excel-cat6a-unscreened-u-utp-booted-patch-leads/) seems to be also very durable. Not endorsing any product, just the type of design.

Comment: What are they doing, yanking the cable out of their machine? I've had the same cable for years and it's still functional.

Comment: Dunno, the clips break and that's that.

Comment: Search for `RJ45 Pouches Jacket`, maybe it increases lifetime.

Comment: You don't describe your environment - if it's a company environment, where people are likely to use similar equipment, I'd advice you to use docking stations. Or just get a tool set and replace connectors.

Comment: How about switching to wireless instead?

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker The OP explicitly asks for options "other than wireless".

Comment: Try to use high quality CAT6A connectors which are more rugged

Comment: @SharatYadav Are they? Really?

Answer (score 3):

Very weird question but I'd be tempted to buy a whole bunch of short cheapo 0.5m-1m cables and just switch out those instead of trying to find some, probably mythical, super-strong ones myself. Not exactly the green approach but it'll work.

Comment: This. I mean, there's [these](http://www.parts-express.com/pe/showdetl.cfm?partnumber=092-181&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=pla), but ruggedized cabling is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't actually an unusual problem.

There's a whole range of networking hardware and paraphrenalia designed for rough/industrial environments.

A quick google for "industrial rj45" turned up things like this:

- [Something from 3M](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Interconnect/Home/Products/ProductCatalog/Catalog/?PC_7_RJH9U5230O73D0ISNF9B3C3SI1000000_nid=ZXDGN1LXQGitPBF9SM2BBQglMZJ02GZ961bl)
- [Something from Provertha](http://www.provertha.com/produkte/steckverbinder/ethernet%20rj45?lang=en)

There's even some which are good up to [IP67](http://www.conec.com/catalogs/c1/ip67/ip67-rj45-industrial-ethernet-connector-system/rj45-patch-cord.html).

Answer (score 1):

Lots of people use a RJ45 cable for their laptop, plug/unplug everyday for years without any problem. In my whole life I never saw a RJ45 falling out (well, in 20 years). I suspect your users do something you don't know.

If you want them to plug something into their own RJ45 female, you can't have any other choice than using a RJ45 male.

Comment: Think hotdesk environment. cables go dead before you blink